# How do I find new quests in wow?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm a level 13 Paladin in World of Warcraft, and I don't have any quests left to complete.  I can't find any more.  Is there some way to get more quests?

Comment: Welcome to the site Anna! You're not really asking a question here, and so your question has been closed. May I suggest consulting the [Wow Wiki](http://www.wowwiki.com/) to help you find a quest?

Comment: Not asking a question?  Am I missing something here?  It seems like an okay question to me.

Comment: @Anna can you mention what you've tried and where you've looked already?  That information might be helpful in determining how to help you.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but LessPop's answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72500/need-a-new-questline) should help.

Comment: Seems like a valid question to me, all these downvotes ~_~ In azure watch, so the answer would be to either get a few more levels to see if any new quests show up or find the next camp to get quests from.

Comment: @brian you didn't see what it looked like before we cleaned it up, that's why there is so many downvotes, also, its stupid easy to find new quests in wow with just a LITTLE bit of personal research. also a likely reason for downvotes

Comment: @Brian Downvotes don't automatically mean invalid questions.

Comment: @Ender I did, and it got edited and fixed. Edits to make clearer > just down voting. And Fluttershy that was in regards to the first comment, not the downvotes :)

Comment: What _race_ are you playing?

Comment: Which faction, horde or alliance?

Answer (score 2):

Go find another area to level up.

You may have already finished all the quests in your starting area, so it's probably time to move on to the next one.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

After level 10 you can move onto a new area. If you have no quests. Find your way to a main alliance city like Stormwind or IronForge and go to a bulletin. The bulletin will give you a quest to a zone area.